# how to search comma separated field in database rails mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I have tags column in my table

And tags field will have datas like

```
1. PHP, Ruby on Rails
2. PHP
3. Javascript, PHP, Ruby on Rails
```

Consider this as my filter

```
PHP(2)
Ruby on Rails(5)
Javascript(0)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this tag management?

Answer (score 1):

Tags should be normalized and then you can make an SQL query, grouping by label.

Models like this should do it.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :Tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end
```

Comment: What are the entities, you are tagging?

Answer (score 0):

You have options here.

- [Has and belongs to many (HABTM) association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
- [Has many through (HTM) association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

You have posts, each post has many tags, each tag is found in many posts. Deep inside this is done through an extra table: you have a list of `posts`, a list of `tags` and a list of pairs `post-tag`. Performance is good, this is what relational databases were designed for.

Because you probably don't need to specify extra data on any specific pairs of a post and its tag (like when the tag's been assigned to a post, if that could be useful), you should use HABTM because it's simpler.

Speaking of post count on each tag: you can use a feature called `counter_cache` (see the same page, linked above), that could keep track of how many associated posts are there in each tag.